# How to identify the installer software type(whether it's NSIS, Inno, Windows Installer etc.)?

Tags: installation

I need to detect what type of installer software is being used for a particular software. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a common way to do it which fits each vendor. I can only talk about Windows Installer based vendors, like InstallShield and WiX. If you use extra functionality provided by a certain vendor (built on top of usual Windows Installer stuff), this can be various custom MSI tables or just specific MSI properties. The [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557.aspx) tool and verbose installation log file are helpful tools.